# replacing remote package with local directory

Tags: mysql, go

I'm playing around with this[enter link description here](https://github.com/mantishK/gonotevanilla/blob/master/config/dbconn.go) Go CRUD api app. The READ.me advises that mysql needs to be configured in `config/dbconn.go`. In the source code, mysql is configured to use port 3306. I cloned the source code and changed the config to use port 8889, which MAMP mysql requires me to use for my own scripts (the only mysql I have on my system is through MAMP).

```
dbUserName := "root"
dbPass := "root"
dbIp := "127.0.0.1"
dbPortNo := 8889
```

When I ran cloned version of the app and tried to visit one of the routes, I got this error message

```
Create tables failed dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connection refused
exit status 1
```

So I'm assuming that it's trying to connect on the port through 3306, and when I look in the `util.go` file of the project, I see that it's importing the config from the remote repo, rather (I'm assuming) than using the config file in the local repo that I changed to use the mysql settings for MAMP

**util.go**

```
import (

    "github.com/mantishK/gonotevanilla/config"

)
```

My question is, if the problem is as I think it is, how do I tell util.go to use the database config file at `/config/dbconn.go` rather than the file that's in the remote repo.

I tried to using

```
 "config"
```

and

```
 "/config"
```

and I got the same error

Comment: This looks to me like a fundamental misunderstanding of what those imports are, and what the `GOPATH` environment variable has to do with it. Where did you change the port? In `dbconn.go` in `$GOPATH/github.com/gonotevanilla/config/dbconn.go`? Or somewhere else? It's not a "remote repo" in the sense that it "live builds" the code at github. You should have used `go get` to download that repo and now there is a `github.com` folder in your GOPATH.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead yes I changed the port in /config/dbconn.go in the repo that I cloned and which I'm running the code with `go run main.go` and you're right, I've probably got a fundamental misunderstanding

Comment: @SimonWhitehead but if it downloads that repo and that repo is trying to connect on port 3306, how can I change it to use the port that I need?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead ok, thanks, I found the `github.com` folder and changed the port number but I got refused connection for the new port. Some progress I guess

Comment: Glad you're making progress. The fact that the connection details are in the source make it less `go get`abble than one can expect from a normal repo. Most repo's move that out into consuming code so that it can be changed per-project. This repo seems to hard code it for learning purposes though.